# byte[] to byte[int] - C#

Tags: c#, byte

Well, this problem has been causing me problems for quite some time now :-(

in short, I have this code :

```
        byte[] code;
        byte[] moreCodes;
        int x = moreCodes.Length;
        code = moreCodes[x]; // Error !!
```

I have also tried the method

```
for(int i = 0; i < moreCodes.Length; i++)
   {
       code = moreCodes[i]; // Error !!
   }
```

So my question is, how to apply/copy several bytes of code to an empty byte container ? 
The byte[] code is currently empty, I want to make this byte contain the full contents of moreCodes.

An alternative idea I had is to use the for loop & apply moreCodes to itself, like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < moreCodes.Length; i++)
   {
       moreCodes = moreCodes[i] ; // Error !!
   }
```

Any ideas on how to achieve a fix to this problem would be greatly appreciated, I feel like this is a silly issue that I should be able to solve, but it's defiantly one of those I just can't get my head around.

Thanks for reading

Comment: If you really want to copy the full content, and moreCodes already have content in it, it's simply `byte[] code = moreCodes;`. Are you trying to achieve something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can't compile because you are mixing byte arrays with single bytes.  Arrays hold bytes, but it makes no sense to try to make an array equal to just one byte.

Also, at runtime, you will be getting an error on `moreCodes.Length`.

That's because you don't have "an empty byte container", you don't have any container at all.

Try

```
List<byte> moreCodes = new List<byte>();
```

and then you can add to it

```
moreCodes.Add(0xAA);
```

and when all your data is added, turn it into an array:

```
code = moreCodes.ToArray();
```

Or, if you know the desired length in advance, you can use an array:

```
byte[] moreCodes = new byte[72];  // here [72] specifies the size
for( int i = 0; i < moreCodes.Length; ++i )
    moreCodes[i] = (byte)i; // here [i] accesses one byte within the array
```

Comment: That's a really great answer, and finally I understand the use of the commonly used List method. Thanks !